# On a product list page, how far should the items be?

Tags: website-design, design, interface

I have the product list page below defined and I'm having trouble figuring out what information should be associated with what.

For example:

- Should the filtering group on the left be closer to the products on the right and further from the title, or at the same distance from both?
- Should the title be at the same distance from the filter and products/filters?

I think is the relationship between things.
Anyway, any suggestions for improvements are also welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMO:

1. Title belongs more in the right content part above product listing. (As it is describing those products in general, and not only their characteristics / filters left in sidebar).
2. "Delete all filters" should be moved left to filter items, as last item. And renamed shorter "Clear all" i.e.
3. Red color signalizes warning, green is more appropriate for discount and price
4. If you place crossed line old price first one, and after that actual price, it will loook as flow / user will be able to compare prices better

Answer (score 0):

I would put the title aligned with the products and on the sidebar filter I would show on top another filter that shows Iluminaticao LED and his children with the Lampadas checked. I hope this makes sense. If you wish I can make a sketch fast.

Comment: It would be great if you could make a quick sketch! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate the whole section that is for input indicators on top (chips and clear search).

IMO:

1. Tedious to have a double function.
2. Straightforward for users to perform tasks (select and delete) in the same area and flow.